# Reload a page and reset URL

Tags: javascript, php, url, events, reload

I am getting a list of items from a mySQL database table, however I have some filters on the page, these filters are responsable for changing values of the variables responsable for storing the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` values on the query.

The way I do this is changing the `location.href` through JavaScript and the PHP variables get the data with `$_GET[]`. When `$_GET[]` is not set, for example, in the first access to the page, some pattern values are sent to the query.

```
function itensPorPag() {

    let qtde = document.getElementById('select_itens').value;
    let order = document.getElementById('order_page').value;

    let offset = 0;

    let url = 'adm_conta.php?prod_qtde='+qtde+'&offset='+offset;

    location.href = url;

}
```

Original URL:

```
adm_conta.php
```

URL after filters:

```
adm_conta.php?prod_qtde=4&offset=0
```

Setting variables:

```
if (isset($_GET['prod_qtde'])) {
    $limit = $_GET['prod_qtde'];
    $offset = $_GET['offset'];
} else {
    $limit = '3';
    $offset = '0';
}
```

So far so good. The problem starts when I need to reload the page without applying any filter, like pressing `F5`, for instance. It because if I just reload the page, the variables will receive the values from the URL, since `$_GET[]` is set.

URL after filters:

```
adm_conta.php?prod_qtde=4&offset=0
```

URL after reloading page (it doesn't change, since it is receiving the same values):

```
adm_conta.php?prod_qtde=4&offset=0
```

I found a solution for this, but it is lacking a little part. I am using the `keyup event` in JavaScript to change the URL when the page is reloaded by pressing `F5`, `CTRL + R` and `CTRL + F5`:

```
document.onkeyup = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 82 && e.ctrlKey || e.keyCode == 116 && e.ctrlKey || e.keyCode == 116) {

        location.href = 'adm_conta.php';
    } 
}
```

It works very well. But I also need to be able to do the same when reloading the page by clicking on the reload button, and that is what is missing.

This button:

[image]

I have tried to use `window.onbeforeunload`, but it will be triggered whenever the page reloads, what would trouble my application, since the page is reloaded after a filter being applied and in this case I can't reset the URL.

How could I do that?

I am oppened to suggestions, even if I have to change the way I am doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use PHP function [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

So after setting ur variables

```
if (isset($_GET['prod_qtde'])) {
$limit = $_GET['prod_qtde'];
$offset = $_GET['offset'];
} else {
    $limit = '3';
    $offset = '0';
}
```

and using them for you know what just send header to redirect user browser to same location but without url query.

Examples with usage:

> header("Refresh:0");

=> refresh same page (maybe best solution)

> header("Refresh:0; url=adm_conta.php");

=> refresh with redirect

Comment: It wouldn't work, because it is not just about reseting the URL, I need to reset it in a specific situation, when the reload button is clicked.

Comment: Then you should change ur logic because in your js code you are refering to default refresh buttons which always get executed before js because its browser thing. Example this code works if you press ctrl and f1 `document.onkeyup = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 111 && e.ctrlKey) {
 console.log('trigger')
        location.replace('adm_conta.php');
    } 
}` To make button refresh  `<input type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="checkKey();">`

Comment: I see. But as I said in my question, with `F5`, `CTRL + R` it is working fine. You 
would be right if I was using `onkeydown`, but with `onkeyup` it works properly. What I need now is to detect clicks on the refresh button on the page. I'll add an image on my question and it will be clear.

Comment: Use [e.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) if you have problem with default behaviour.